# ajax call fails to return true or false to the submit event

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, return-value

I will just come right to it.

I  need to know how I can return false or true to a `submitbutton`.
I read some other post here, that says it cannot be done from within a ajax success function
because it will return to the ajax context and not the submit event.

**Maybe someone has a workaround for this??**
also in the context that I am loading a form from another page.

Some background:

I **load a form from another page** and **in the callback, I write the submit function**
because otherwise I don't have a way to connect to the submit button.
In the submit function I check the input for some fields.
If everything checks out, it proceeds with the ajax call to a php script.

Answer (score 2):

In the [success callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) of the AJAX request which refreshes the `form` you could reattach the [submit event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) handler to it.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I edited my question. The unwanted behaviour is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Solved it by using someone else's suggestion to put the ajax call in a click event and when necessary, use `$('form').submit();`

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))